# How to handle exception while adding duplicate username to a database in spring mvc application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I am building spring mvc application. I want to dissalow adding duplicate(username is primary key) entry and inform in view to choose another username.

I am working on register user option. Everything works until I put user with username that already exist. Well, It was deliberate because username column is a primary key in my database.

I am looking for an option to handle this so:

This is my SQL table

```
 create table users(
  username varchar(50) not null primary key,
  password varchar(50) not null);
```

This is my repository:

```
@Repository

class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;


    @Override
    public void addUser(User user) throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException {
        /*language=SQL*/
        String SQL_ADD_USER= "INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)";

        String username  = user.getUsername();
        String password  = user.getPassword();
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_ADD_USER, username, password);

    }
}
```

and this is part of my Controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String registerPage(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){return "register";}

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegisterUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){

    try {
        userRepository.addUser(user);
    } catch (com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException e) {

        //some line of code that would add information to the view that user with given username already exists.
    }


    return "redirect:/login";
}
```

As you can see I tried to handle an exception that occurs during adding duplicate entry. This is why I put this clause `throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` in public void addUser(User user). In the next step I wanted to handle this exception in `public String processRegisterUser` method so that I could inform user in view that given username is occupied. Well, It doesn't work. I can't handle `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException` and during adding duplicate error instead of warning in view I get:

```
 HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)]; Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'

type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)]; Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

    org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO users VALUES (?,?)]; Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'user' for key 'PRIMARY'
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
        org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
        org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
```

If you need any details please comment.

Comment: Do you have jsp page for displaying registration form?

Comment: I do. It works fine. Well, I didn't adda ny field to display error message in registration form yet. But it dosen't matter. I put some rediraction in try-catch block for testing

Comment: I can tell you how I managed to make it work for me - but in my case I used Hibernate validation for this, not an exception. Would you like to hear my example or you want to stick to exceptions part?

Comment: @lenach87 Sure. I am interested how proffesional programmers solve this problem. I am open to your anwer. I am glad for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I double checked, what I was doing, was not checking the uniqueness, but other things (valid email pattern, number of letters in password) - but with uniqueness such thing is not working. Sorry again for confusing

Comment: @lenach87 this is not a problem. Thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using spring jdbcTemplate for db connection and it has his own exception hierarchy, so you can try to catch the spring exception org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException

Comment: You are right I just swap  MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException with  DuplicateKeyException. I am beginner and I am wonderwing how would pro developer handle my problem. I mean not allowing to use the same username, email again in web application during registration.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Query.uniqueResult()`  as decribed in this [article](http://skillshared.blogspot.nl/2013/03/dont-use-querylist-when-you-really-need.html) or [else](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/)

```
public Account getAccountByAccountIdAndType(Long accountId, AccountType accountType) {

    Account account = null;
    try {
        Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery("getAccountByAccountId");
        query.setLong("accountId", accountId); 
        query.setString("accountType", AccountType.SAVING.toString());
        Account account = (Account)Query.uniqueResult();
    } catch(NonUniqueResultException) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Two account found with same account number and type : Acc No-" + accountId);
    }
    if (account == null) {
         throw new RuntimeException("Unable to find Account for account number :" + accountId);
    }
    return account;
}
```

Entity class

```
@NamedQuery(
name = "getAccountByAccountId",
query = "from Account where username = :username")
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are handling only MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException not other exceptions: NestedServletException and DuplicateKeyException and hence you are getting stacktrace and your try/catch is not working.

BTW, Why not simply create an extra method to check if the username is already present and if yes then display error message otherwise add user.

```
class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository{
    //.....
    public int isUsernameExist(String username){
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=?";
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new Object[] { username }, String.class);
    }
    //....
}

@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String processRegisterUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result){
    int status = userRepository.isUserExist(user.getUsername());
    if(status==1){
        //Username exist... redirect and display error msg.
    } else {
        userRepository.addUser(user);
    }
    //.....
}
```

Comment: Well, this seems fine to check if the user exists and add it. but well is it efficient solution? Well suppose that we want to register user in fb dtabse which have so many users. I am interested how to proffesional programmers solve this this problem. There must be some recommended pattern to solve this problem.

Comment: In case of millions of transactions, there can be overhead issues since there is 2 calls to the database. BTW, if you want to handle duplicate username error with exception, simply use Exception instead of MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException  so that it can handle all kind of exceptions.

Comment: Well, I can handle exception. But anyway. Is it a good practice to solve my problem with handling exception? I am wondering how some pro developer would solve this.

Comment: Well, only if you know what exception will thrown. Its up to the developer to solve this kind of problem and the problem nature. But if talking about benefits, in case of not only duplicate primary key but also database server down or internal error in database, using exception can be very helpful.

Comment: Checking to see if a user exists before adding the user would lead to a race condition. If two users wanted to create the same user at the same user one request would fail with an exception that you were trying to avoid.

Comment: This indeed seems to lead to a race condition, as the isUsernameExist method may return outdated data before the register completes, particularly if two users register the same username at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem by catching the exception (to avoid race conditions) and then I would add an error to the BindingResult so that I would be able to display the error in the (JSP/Thymeleaf) view template.

```java
@Controller
public class UserController {

  private final UserService userService;

  public UserController(UserService userService) {

    this.userService = userService;
  }

  /**
   * Adds new a user and redirect to users if there are no errors otherwise return add user template.
   */
  @PostMapping("/admin/add_user")
  public String postUser(Model model, @Valid UserForm userForm, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      // Maybe add attributes to the model here. Do not redirect when there are errors.

      return "add_user";
    }

    try {
      userService.createUser(
          User.withUsername(userForm.getUsername()).password(userForm.getPassword()).roles("ADMIN").build());
    } catch (final DuplicateKeyException e) {
      result.rejectValue("username", "usernameInUse", "Username is already in use");

      return postUser(model, userForm, result);
    }

    // Redirect after post if there are no errors
    return "redirect:/admin/users";
  }

}
```

The user form contains standard jsr 303 validation annotations.

```java
@Data
public class UserForm {

  @Length(min = 1, max = 50)
  @NotEmpty
  private String username;

  @NotEmpty
  private String password;
}
```