# Spring Security: Username already exists exception

Tags: java, spring

I'm using Spring security. Is there any dedicated spring authentication exception type for the case where user wants to signup with a username that already exists?

The closest exception that I could find to my intention was `AuthenticationServiceException` that according to spring doc is "Thrown if an authentication request could not be processed due to a system problem."

Comment: you want to prevent a user to login for 1 time. you can set max session equal 1 in spring security configuration; so a username can be logged only 1 time. if you want to handle  manally, define a AuthenticationEntryPoint to check new loggin username and throw your exception.

Comment: This question is regarding "Signing up" not "Logging in"

Comment: there is same question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771977/how-to-handle-exception-while-adding-duplicate-username-to-a-database-in-spring

Comment: I don't know what is your credentials store but why not simply catch the exception raised when your user wants to duplicate an already existing username. For exemple, in mysql if you set a `unique constraint` in your credentials table an exception will be raised if you want to store a user who already exists.

Comment: And what exception to throw eventually ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException`
Example Class:

```
public class UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException extends AuthenticationException {

    public UserAlreadyExistAuthenticationException(final String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }

}
```